# How are Github's Rails models (Users and Orgs) structured?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, architecture

I'm looking to build an application similar to Github, similar in the sense that you have both Users and Organizations, and these two can have many X (in the case of Github, it's repositories).

Does anyone know what's the best way to go about this? Should I put them both on the same Database table with a 'type' attribute, or just do 2 different tables?

Thanks for any help!

Edit: So the application I have in mind is not meant to host code. It's similar to Github in just that it has Users and Organizations, who both can create X.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been done very well with [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/). You might consider using GitLab, rather than creating your own application. If you do decide to continue, perhaps you can start with a fork of GitLab, or at least crib any relevant portions from their architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I edited the question, I'm not doing a application to host code. It's similar to Github just in that one way.